# Modify tag position with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

Suppose I have following string:

```
var text = "<p>Some text <ins>Text1</p><p>Text2 </ins><ins>Some other text </ins>and another text<ins>Text3</p><p>Text4 </ins></p>"
```

I need to clean up the above string into

```
var text = "<p>Some text Text1</p><p><ins>Text2 </ins><ins>Some other text </ins>and another text Text3</p><p><ins>Text4 </ins></p>"
```

Assume Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4 are random string

I tried below but just mess up:

```
text.replace(/<ins>(.*?)<\/p><p>/g, '</p><p><ins>');
```

Thanks

**ADDITIONAL EXPLANATION**

Take a look at this:

```
<ins>Text1</p><p>Text2 </ins>
```

Above is wrong. It should be:

```
Text1</p><p><ins>Text2 </ins>
```

Comment: You need to describe the logic behind what you want to do

Comment: Added more explanation

Comment: How do you determine which is the correct position of opening/closing tag?

Comment: Correct position for opening tag should be after `<p>`. And the closing tag remain like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following regex:

```js
function posChange() {
  var text = "<p>Some text <ins>Text1</p><p>Text2 </ins><ins>Some other text </ins>and another text<ins>Text3</p><p>Text4 </ins></p>";
  var textnew = text.replace(/(<ins>)([^<]+)(<\/p><p>)([^<]+)/g, '$2$3$1$4');
  alert(textnew);
}
posChange()
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION:**

```
/(<ins>)        1st capturing group (i.e: <ins>)....$1
 ([^<]+)        2nd capturing group (i.e: Text1)....$2
 (<\/p><p>)     3rd capturing group (i.e: </p><p>)..$3
 ([^<]+)        4th capturing group (i.e: Text2 )...$4
          /g    match all occurrences
```

Based on the requirements, for each match:

```
Original String:  $1 $2 $3 $4 
should be replaced with
New String:       $2 $3 $1 $4
```

In this way, the position of each capturing group gets shifted with the help of regex.

Comment: thanks this work. Would be great if you provide some explanation

Comment: I'm sorry i can't upvote. Will upvote after I gain sufficient reputation

Comment: @Primadi: Added the explanation of regex. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all `<ins>`:

```
text = text.replace(/<ins>/g, '');
```

and then replace every string ending with `</ins>` and not containing any tag with sum of `<ins>` and this string:

```
var matches = text.match(/[^<>]+<\/ins>/g)
for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) { 
    text = text.replace(matches[i], '<ins>' + matches[i]);
}
```

result:

```
<p>Some text Text1</p><p><ins>Text2 </ins><ins>Some other text </ins>and another textText3</p><p><ins>Text4 </ins></p>
```

Comment: It just deleting ins tag

Comment: The second part aims to put `<ins>` tags in "right" place